# ESB Toolkit - No response from web service when using Orchestration Extender

Tags: biztalk, esb, biztalk-2010, orchestration, biztalk-orchestrations

I have the following itinerary:
[image: Test Itinerary]

- A one way receive location passes a message to an orchestration where an inner message is extracted (unable to do this in a map).
- The returned message from the orchestration is then mapped and the
  result of that map, mapped again. Using the Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Services.Transform service.
- This is then passed to a web service, via the Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Services.Routing service, which fires fine but I am not receiving the expected response which I want to write to file. The message that does get written to the file is the message passed to the web service rather than the expected response.  Testing the web service using a simpler itinerary i.e. one without orchestration extenders shows that the web service works as expected.
- The  OffRamp is from the GlobalBank.ESB example application.

How can I get the required response from the web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally managed to find a solution to this for which I have to give full credit to [this guy](https://www.linkedin.com/in/vikasbhardwaj)

> The problem is Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Services.Routing Service only provides one way operation, so even if you mark your resolver with two-way message exchange pattern it wont work.
>
> If you check Microsoft.Practices.ESB application in BizTalk Admin console, it has one one way dynamic send port Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Agents_2.1.0.0_Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Agents.Delivery_DeliveryPort_31bf3856ad364e35 which is bound to orchestration Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Agents.Delivery. When you use Orchestration extender and use Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Services.Routing service, this port is used to send any call and because this is one way port, you do not get response.
>
> You need to use a Two-way orchestration in callwebservice shape. A sample Two-way orchestration is in MultipleWebServices ESB Sample. If you deploy that orchestration and register it as itinerary service and use it in callwebservice shape, it will work.

and it more or less did :) Deploy the orchestration and register it to the ESB as an itinerary service by adding an entry to the esb config between the itineraryServices node:

```
          <itineraryService id="04BD6120-06E4-43D3-A56F-2FF061D59862" name="ESB.MultipleWebServices.Orchestrations.TwoWayRouting" type="ESB.MultipleWebServices.Orchestrations.TwoWayRouting, Biztalk.EsbGeneric.Orchestrations, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=140bc5dcbb9afcea" scope="Orchestration" stage="None"/>
```

Create an id using guidgen, the type is made up of the name and assembly of the orchestraiton (comma seperated) in the Admin Console and will vary depending on the application that you have deployed to. scope and stage are as shown above.

Initially I had an error on the send port Biztalk.HoopleEsbGeneric.Orchestrations_1.0.0.0_ESB.MultipleWebServices.Orchestrations.TwoWayRouting_RoutingPort_140bc5dcbb9afcea but changing the send and receive pipelines to PassThruTransmit and PassThruReceive respectively solved this.